# Destroying Indy Context from the outside

Tags: delphi, indy

What's the proper way of destroying `TIdContext` descendant from the outside? I want to close a particular (hanging) connection and destroy its context.

Say, I'm taking an element from `TIdCustomTCPServer.Contexts` and... Calling `Free` is not enough I guess. I just want to avoid any pitfalls. Sometimes Indy is not intuitive at all.

Comment: Don't use brute force. Find the reason why the connection hangs. Is it running code in an infinite loop? Is it waiting for an event or data that never arrives?

Comment: @mjn42 I need this. Trust me :)

Comment: We don't need to trust you.  We need to see your actual code.  What mjn42 said is correct.  You need to find the reason for the hang and fix it. If you are using Indy correctly, it should not be hanging.  Now, it is possible that maybe you are simply stuck in a blocking read/write operation that "hangs" because the client is not doing something correctly on its end. That is a different issue. Indy uses blocking socket I/O, but it also supports timeouts, so you could utilize those timeouts to exit blocking I/Os if they take too long, and then you can close the connection if needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know. I just need a quick and dirty workaround that will win me some time to debug deeper. There's too much code to be posted there, so it's my own job to find the reason. But currently I just need a relieble way to kill a context without any negative side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use something like this. Do not free any context

```
var
  i: Integer;
  list: TList;
begin
  list := IdTCPServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  try
    for i := 0 to list.Count-1 do
    begin
      try
        TIdContext(list.Items[i]).Connection.Disconnect;
       except

       end;
    end;
  finally
    IdTCPServer1.Contexts.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

> What's the proper way of destroying TIdContext descendant from the outside?

To NOT DO IT at all.  You do not own the Context objects, you have no business destroying them.  The server owns them, it will manage them for you.

> I want to close a particular (hanging) connection and destroy its context.

The Context is destroyed automatically when its owning thread terminates.  By default, that thread terminates when the associated socket is closed.  Make sure your event handlers are NOT blocking exceptions, unless you call `Disconnect()` manually.

> Say, I'm taking an element from TIdCustomTCPServer.Contexts and... Calling Free is not enough I guess.

Please DO NOT destroy the Context directly.  However, you *can* call `Context.Connection.Disconnect()` instead.